# my schema has a "messages" table I can't drop with migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, rails-activerecord, rails-migrations

My schema has a messages table that I can't drop with a migration. When I try to drop the table I get `PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "messages" does not exist`. How can this be if the schema.rb is *the authoritative source for your database schema*?

Comment: If you drop a table manually (not using migrations) the schema.rb file does not get magically updated.

Comment: along with @mischa said it might be out of sync, you can `bundle exec rake db:schema:dump`   to regenerate it.

Comment: regenerated the schema and the tables were not present.

Answer (score 1):

Migrations don't work that way. They are just a series of scripts that get executed in order to get from version A to version B. Rails determines which version is current by looking at the schema_migrations table.

To solve Your specific problem, either edit the migration file, or create a dummy 'messages' table that the migration can drop.